# default select value on page open

Tags: php

I have difficulties thinking how to set default select value on opening page edit.php. So when I open edit.php it would show different value in select boxes getting value from database. Right now first value opens which is blank. I want that opening edit.php page select drop down list would choose default value from database `colour` table. So if mysql `colour` table would be 3 than it`s select default value Blue. It it`s 4 than default select value would be Gray.

SQL

`colour` = 3

Code: main.php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `colour` FROM `properties`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if($row['colour'] == 1) { echo ''; }
    else if($row['colour'] == 2) { echo '<b>Colour:</b> Brown'; }
    else if($row['colour'] == 3) { echo '<b>Colour:</b> Blue'; }
    else if($row['colour'] == 4) { echo '<b>Colour:</b> Gray'; }
```

Code: edit.php

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post" >
    <select name="colour">
            <option value="1" <?php if (@$_POST['colour']=='1') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>></option>
            <option value="2" <?php if (@$_POST['colour']=='2') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Brown</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if (@$_POST['colour']=='3') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Blue</option>
            <option value="4" <?php if (@$_POST['colour']=='4') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Gray</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Never user '@' sign like You did before $_POST table. It is not efficient and silently fails.

Comment: I want to achieve that when opening edit.php page the select drop down list would choose default value from different database`s values. If mysql database `colour` would be 3 than edit.php would show Blue. If mysql database `colour` would be 4 than edit.php default select drop down value would be Gray.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass color variables on edit page.
For example:

```
<option value="1" <?=($color==1)?'selected="true"':'' ?> ></option>
<option value="2" <?=($color==2)?'selected="true"':'' ?> >Brown</option>
```

and so on...

Here, `$color` is coming from database selected value.

You don't need POST variable if you want to get value from database.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be much easier when you do this on client side. You need to change

```
<select name="colour">
```

to

```
<select name="colour" id="colour">
```

then put this code in your `edit.php`

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var select = document.getElementById("colour");
    select.value = 3; //now, 3 is the default value of your select
};
</script>
```